# UINavigation Bar tutorial

Tags: ios

I want to add a navigation bar in a xib interface with class files in a separate group. And the navigation bar should have a back button, if i click the back button it will go the view in another xib in the another group. Is there any tutorial regarding this navigation bar which used for navigation between two separate xib groups in ios.

Comment: Go to google.com just write uinavigationbar tutorial. There are lots of tutorial on UINavigationController

Comment: Help him find a link instead of downvote!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sampleViewController *viewController = [[sampleViewController alloc]init];    
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:Nil];
```

write the above in a button action like: (as back button where the `UIView` you want to go)

```
-(IBAction)moveview:(id)sender
{

}
```

`sampleViewController` is the view which you wants to navigate from the current view.

Answer (score 0):

This is a detailed discussion by Apple on `ViewControllers`. It covers `Navigation Controller` significantly.
You will gain a lot by going through this programming guide:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH1-SW1

After reading through this, you can learn a lot about `UINavigationController`, its methods, properties, and other stuff from below link:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

sampleViewController *viewController = [[sampleViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"sampleViewController" Bundle:NULL];

[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:Nil];